# free() on char* recognized as invalid by valgrind

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, valgrind, free

I am attempting to free char* pointers that exist within a char** array, but valgrind is determining this operation as invalid.

Here is a simple example of what I'm doing:

```
struct building{
  int propertyPrice;
  int totalArea;
  char** floors;
}

int main(){

  struct building* B = malloc(sizeof(struct building));

  for(size_t i=0;i<10;i++)
    B->floors[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char*));

}
```

Here's where I'm confused - I can access the elements with the following loop:

```
for(size_t i=0;i<10;i++)
    printf("%s", B->floors[i]); //assume that a valid string exists at each floors[i]!
```

I am *attempting* to free the allocated memory as follows:

```
for(size_t i=0;i<10;i++)
    free(B->floors[i]);

free(B);
```

*Please excuse the lack of malloc() check against NULL, I'm cutting that out for brevity.*

Valgrind determines that the operation `free(B->floors[i])` is `Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()`. Yet, if I can access the individual char* elements through `B-floors[i]`, shouldn't I be able to free it using the same syntax by just switching the function call from `printf()` to `free()` (I got the idea from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815937/valgrind-invalid-free-delete-delete-realloc-in-c))?

The second `free()` call works perfectly fine.

My program is executing as expected, but I'd like to get rid of memory leaks - hence the usage of valgrind. If it's helpful, I'm using the `-Werror -ggdb` switches for gcc and the `--track-origins=yes --leak-check=full` arguments when executing valgrind.

Comment: `B->floors` is a pointer, but you never make it point anywhere. You need e.g. `B->floors = malloc(10 * sizeof *B->floors)` before the loop. And of course `free(B->floors)` once you're done with it (*after* the loop to free each element).

Comment: It is also possible to define `floors` as a *flexible array member* `char *floors[];` and extend the allocation of `B` to incorporate the required number of elements: `struct building *B = malloc(sizeof(*B) + 10 * sizeof(B->floors[0]));`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
for(size_t i=0;i<10;i++)
    B->floors[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char*));
```

`B->floors` is used uninitialized.

You need to reserve space for 10 elements:

```
B->floors = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
```

then you can fill the jagged array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    B->floors[i] = strdup(...); // or malloc + memcpy if strdup is not available
}
```

finally:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    free(B->floors[i]);
}
free(B->floors);
```

Since `floors` is the last member of the array you can use it as a "flexible array member":

```
struct building* B = malloc(sizeof(struct building) + (sizeof(char *) * 10));
```

in this case you don't call `free(B->floors);` at the end.

Comment: This would just get the OP an uninitialized array of 20 `char *` pointers.  I suspect that's not all of what's needed, but the question is incomplete...

Comment: While that took care of the heap allocation, if I don't initialize the embedded char* pointers now valgrind complains that `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` and that this `Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation`.

This is why I initially used the malloc loop and set the embedded char* pointers to a default value.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  each pointer needs to point to some valid address on the stack or reserved with `strdup` or `malloc` + `memcpy` of course, I assume OP knows that but edited anyway.

Comment: @DavidRanieri why on the stack?

Comment: @DavidRanieri: Apparently, if I just use calloc() instead of malloc() the errors disappear. However, just to test that my understanding is correct, this is because calloc() would initialize the char* pointers to NULL, yes? And that this is a secure way to handle this situation?

Comment: @0___________ why not? `char str[][4] = {"abc", "def", ...}; ... B->floors[i] = str[i];` is an option.

Comment: @smellyourbooks using `calloc` doesn't fix the problem, you still don't have space for 10 elements in the jagged array.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Tried to do it the `malloc() + memcpy()` way, ended up getting a SIGSEV.

For reference: 

```for(size_t i=0;i<17;i++){
     B->floors[i] = malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
     memcpy(B->floors[i], "INITIALIZATION_VALUE", 17);
    }
```

And then free via the loop route mentioned above.

Comment: @DavidRanieri no, as ypu cant `free` as in the question.

Comment: @smellyourbooks "INITIALIZATION_VALUE" doesn't fit in 17 bytes, you need 20 bytes + 1 for the trailing NUL.

Comment: After fixing the 21 bytes error, valgrind is again saying that the loop statement `free(B->floors[i])` is `Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()`! (The previous errors have disappeared completely, thank you.)

Comment: @0___________ are you aware that I was answering to a comment? _I suspect that's not all of what's needed_. I mean each pointer in a jagged array must point to a valid address regardless of the logic of the question.

Comment: I'd just like conclude that this answer was perfect. Turns out, I was assigning a char* pointer values via the `=` operator when I should I have used `memcpy` within an internal function that was causing memory issues. Thank you @DavidRanieri for all your help!